# Integrating async into syncronous python calls

Tags: python, asynchronous, session, python-asyncio

I have an async implementation that reads json information from about 10,000 websites.
When I run it from inside the same .py file it runs extremely quicky (250-300 it/s).

However, I want to include this async task into a syncronous task so that the sync task does some tasks to get the list of urls, passes it to the async tasks which performs a simple task on all urls, and then returns a list. When I try to run this externally (another sync py file), I get very slow operations (14-20 it/s).

When I call `asyncio.run(main(urls))` from within the .py file it works well, but calling it from another file which runs syncronously results in a very slow operation.

I am quite new to async but I feel like this should be possible!

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import tqdm.asyncio

async def get_json(url, session, sem):
    async with sem, session.get(url) as resp:
        data = await resp.json()
        #do something with data

async def tq(tasks):
    for f in tqdm.asyncio.tqdm.as_completed(tasks):
        await f

async def main(urls):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10000)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_json(url, session, sem)) for url in urls]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, tq(tasks))
```

This section of code is called:

```
import geturls as gu #geturls.py the name of the code above
import subprocess
import asyncio

def runJS(update_auth):
    resp = subprocess.getoutput(str('node geturls.js'+ update_auth))
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_auth = '12345'
    ar_list, = runJS(update_auth),
    asyncio.run(gu.main(ar_list))
```

**EDIT**: It seems I found the issue (though I don't know how to fix it).
When I pass the test url database I am actually passing: `urls = [url1,url2,url3,url4,url5] * 2000` to achieve 10,000 urls. However of course they are not unique.
I have created a new very simple py that calls my async and provides it with a unique list or the urls*2000 and the latter is completed at least 10x faster. I suppose this is actually my problem I am trying to solve

Comment: So if this works fine for you, maybe you should show us the code that _doesn't_ work so well? From what you're telling it sounds like there is something going on in your calling code that probably has nothing to do with asyncio.

Comment: You don't need to call `asyncio.create_task()` to schedule coroutines which you are going to `gather()`. The `gather()` call will schedule them for you.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword you are right. I have added the call

Comment: @vaizki I'm not entirely sure how I would call the gather task without a task list. Do you have a reference or some possible code?

Comment: Sorry, but that is effectively almost the same as before. You should produce a minimal example that produces the error you want to show us (at least when run on your machine, best when run on any machine). The way it is now, this should throw an exception because `urls` will not be defined on import. If you do not uncomment `urls` the whole thing will run twice, because you don't have a `if __name__ == "__main__:"` guard before `asyncio.run` in geturls.py.

Comment: @novastorm `tasks = [ get_json(url, session, sem) for url in urls ]` is enough to generate a list of awaitables which `gather(*tasks)` will then schedule.

Comment: @vaizki That did not work for me. I received a runtime error `RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine` and a task exception `Task exception was never retrieved`

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword sorry again. I am trying to add information but not too much verbosity so that it is hard to find important information. Thanks for your patience.

I have added the code as I run it now, and I have added a small snippet of what I think the problem is. Now I just need to find a solution to that